# Как правильно реализовать морфинг Hamburger'а в back button?

Tags: android, архитектура

Я хочу использовать подход: "каждому фрагменту свой `Toolbar`".
Как в этом случае правильно реализовывать анимацию морфинга
`Hamburger` -> `BackButton`
при переходах между фрагментами?

Answer (score 4):

У вас получается такая ситуация: `Toolbar` принадлежит фрагменту, а иконка внутри `Toolbar` отображает состояние стека фрагментов внутри активити.

Если вам действительно нужна эта анимация перехода от гамбургера к стрелке, то есть два варианта:

1) Делаете **глобальный `Toolbar`** в активити. Но тогда будут все вытекающие кейсы с инфлейтом разных меню и заголовков из конкретных фрагментов.

2) Делаете **в активити метод**, который синхронизирует переданный `Toolbar` с состоянием стека. Но надо не забывать отсоединять `Toolbar`, когда фрагмент уходит с экрана (логично использовать методы старт/стоп)

```
fun attachToolbarNavigationIcon(toolbar: Toolbar) {}
fun dettachToolbarNavigationIcon() {}
```

*ЗЫ:* Есть более простой вариант. Скорее всего анимация из "гамбургера" в кнопку "назад" вам нужна только при переходе с первого фрагмента на следующий. В остальных случаях там висит только кнопка "назад".
Поэтому можно это обработать только в рамках первого фрагмента и все: перед переходом вперед - превращаем в кнопку назад и только тогда переходим.
При возврате превращаем обратно в гамбургер.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу дать Вам готового решения, но в общем случае в `support library` есть готовый класс [`DrawerArrowDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawerArrowDrawable.html), который как раз реализует эту морфирущую иконку. Вы всегда можете попробовать добавить её на Ваш `Toolbar` и запустить анимацию после того, как тулбар нового фрагмента добавится на экран. Пример запуска анимации [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34951452/3100967).

Если Вы используете Navigation Drawer, то иконка должна работать "из коробки". [Вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015182/different-toolbar-for-fragments-and-navigation-drawer) есть схожий вопрос с ответами, как при этом использовать разные тулбары (обратите внимание не только на принятый ответ, но и на ответ с большинством голосов).